# How to download files from Git Repository using Java code

Tags: java, git, file, download

I have to download files from Git hub and store them in local file system using java. Can somebody tell me if there is any api to do that?

Comment: you could also access git from a shell through java

Answer (score 1):

Check out JGit: https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/.
The code should be something like:

```
Git.cloneRepository()
        .setURI("https://github.com/...")
        .setDirectory(Paths.get("/path/to/local/").toFile())
        .call();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).